# How to determine if control validation failed?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which programmatically changes the `CurrentCell` property. The problem is; the setter of `CurrentCell` throws an `InvalidOperationException` if validation for the current cell is canceled through the `CellValidating` event. How do I work around this?

Note that a `bool` field is not an option in my case, because I cannot guarantee that a deriving class will use it.

I tried the following probable work-around, it didn't work:

```
void EnterCell(DataGridViewCell cell)
{
    if (!CurrentCell.IsInEditMode || EndEdit())
    {
        CurrentCell = cell;
    }
}
```

Edit:

`cell.Selected` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

[DataGridView.CellValidated Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidated(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Occurs after the cell has finished validating.

Comment: I remember that I tried that event, it didn't work FYI.